# HTML/CSS/JS dragging table column

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I would like to implement a table in JSP page which is something similar to this [Click Here To View](http://www.hotelogix.com/videotut/flash/Single_reservation/How_to_Check_In_a_Reservation.html).

So I can drag the table column from start date to end date and pop up a form. Could you all please suggest me how can I do that in JSP.

Comment: That page is a Flash application. You can't do that with JSP.

Comment: With a good load of JavaScript/Ajax, it'll be doable. But that has indeed nothing to do with JSP. You need to reframe the question as "How can I do that in HTML/CSS/JS?". Once you know that, you just have to rename .html to .jsp and let all JS/ajax actions point to a Servlet URL :) Only, such a question is waay to broad for Stackoverflow. Rather hire a architect/developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have built a draggable column data table in js before. If you do end up doing this instead of using an existing implementation...

i have really good advice: use **fixed table layout**, or you will not succeed.